# How to use $resource to post data in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I try to save comments to my articles

Somewords about my backend and schemas

Articles:

```
var DiscussSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
});
```

Comments:

```
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
       required: 'Please fill Comment name',
       trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    discuss: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Disquss'
    }
});
```

I added routes to server routes for my server controller

```
app.route('/api/discusses/:discussId/comments')
    .all(discussesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .post(discusses.comment);
```

And my Angular service

```
angular.module('discusses').factory('Comments', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/discusses/:discussId/comments', {
                discussId: '@_id'
            }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
        });
    }
]);
```

I tried so many version of addComment in my angular controller  but i always get error - undefined

```
$scope.addComment = function(){
    if($scope.body === '') { return; }
    //Comment service
    Comment.addComment(discuss._id, {
        body: $scope.body,
        user: 'user',
    }).success(function(comment) {
       $scope.discuss.comments.push(comment);
    });
    $scope.body = '';
};
```

How to save comment???

Comment: `Comment.update({_id: discuss._id, body: $scope.body, user: 'user'}).success` or may be .post instead of .update for new entry in db, which depends on server side implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $save method is $resource service as explained in official documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).
To site an example, in your controller you can do something like :
Create an end point '**/api/discusses/comments**'.

```
var CommentResource = $resource('/api/discusses/comments');
$scope.myFun = function(){
    var commentRes = new CommentResource();
    commentRes.discuss_id = 'some..iid';
    commentRes.comment = 'some comment';
    commentRes.someParam = 'some param value';
    
    commentRes.$save(function(result){
         //do something with result..
    });
}
```

**$save** works on **POST** http verb so handle it appropriately in the backend.
You can access all the values passed into $save using **req.body** in express route handler.
You can pass values to angularjs after processing the req.body params and the result will be available in $save callback.
I hope it helps, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you. I get {body: 'First comment', discuss_id = '552a18c952bf34202a2cd0bd', use: Object but i have error GET 500 server  api/disqusses/comments. Why GET? In my angular service return $resource('api/discusses/comments', {
                discussId: '@_id'
            }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },  and i have server routes like this   app.route('/api/disqusses/comments').all(disqussesPolicy.isAllowed)
            .post(disqusses.addcomments);

Comment: why not you use router.post(..) ?